# Can I calculate the sum of two sliders?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to calculate a sum based on values from two sliders that the user sets. This sum is then used to calculate another sum. Can I read the values of two sliders into a procedure, take the sum from it, "save" it and then use this result further?

I tried to use the report function but this doesn't seem to be the right way.

Comment: you're getting downvoted because you aren't posting the code you have tried so far. And for what it's worth, you seem to be asking "does + exist in netlogo?", which seems a little weird. Of course you can sum two values using +.

Answer (score 1):

All sliders are global variables. When creating a slider, you are asked to enter the name of that slider / global variable. You can therefore use this variable in your code.

Assuming your sliders are called `test1`and `test2` you can write a procedure

```
to test-sum-proc
  let test-sum test1 + test2
  set test-sum test-sum + 1
  print test-sum
end
```